# BxSlider doesnt go responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bxslider

I'm testing Bxslider but it doesn't resize when browser window goes larger or smaller.It was supposed to go responsive instantly but it did not .I attach a part of my code for you guys to see:

Here it goes:

```
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.1.1/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.1.1/jquery.bxslider.css"></script>


<div id="slider">
                    <ul class="bxslider">
                        <li><img src="images/1.jpg" ></li>
                        <li><img src="images/2.jpg" ></li>
                        <li><img src="images/3.jpg" ></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
div#slider { 
    width: 100%;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block; 
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    margin:0 auto;

    }



.bx-wrapper img{


    max-width: 100%;

    display:block;
}

div.bx-controls-direction > a.bx-prev{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
     right: 96%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    color: white;

}


div.bx-controls-direction > a.bx-next{

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 96%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  color: white;
}

div.bx-pager-item{

      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
      /*position: absolute;
      top: 239px;*/
}

a.bx-pager-link{
    padding: 0 20px;

}
```

And finally the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

Can you help me out please?

Comment: sure it does, can you provide more html/css beyond `<div id="slider">`?

Comment: I found my mistake. In the css file I wrote `body{
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;

} ` instead of  `body{
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;

} `